# Struts2: List being accessed out of its scope

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

I have a struts2 action class which looks something like this:

```
//import relevant packages

public class Product implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware,
        ServletResponseAware, ServletContextAware {

    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private String price;

    private ServletContext servletContext; 
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest; 
    private HttpServletResponse servletResponse; 
    private Map sessionMap;

    //getters and setters here

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public void setSession(Map map) {
        this.sessionMap = map;
    }

    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        this.servletResponse = servletResponse;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    public String execute() {


       //  do something here
        return "success";
    }

    public List<String> getCountries() {
        List<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        countries.add("Australia");
        countries.add("Fiji");
        countries.add("New Zealand");
        countries.add("Vanuatu");
        return countries;
    }

}
```

sruts.xml has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="package.name" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Product_input">
            <result>/jsp/Product.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Product_save" class="package.name.Product" method="execute">
            <result>/jsp/Details.jsp</result>
        </action>       
    </package>
</struts>
```

Product.jsp consists of a simple form:

```
<s:form action="Product_save">
        <s:textfield label="Product Name" key="productName"/>
        <s:textfield label="Description" key="description"/>
        <s:textfield label="Price" key="price"/>
        <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Details.jsp displays the contents entered in the form:

```
<h5>Details:</h5>
Product Name:
<s:property value="productName" />
<br /> Description:
<s:property value="description" />
<br /> Price: $
<s:property value="price" /> </br>
<s:property value="countries[0]" /> </br>
```

The last line in Details.jsp tries to access the countries list declared in the getCountries() in action class and ideally it should not print anything since the method is never accessed nor the countries list is part of the action class attributes (and hence while creating the object of type Product in the Value stack, it shouldn't have countries).

**But** it does print Australia (the indexed value of list) along with the other form properties. How/Why is this happening?

Comment: `countries[0]` will eventually go to `getCountries().get(0)`,so this getter method is there in your action class and OGNL is able to access it,moreover in your method you are creating a list as well filling it,so what S2 and OGNL is doing is perfectly fine

Comment: In my opinion, your comment it's a perfect answer to this question =)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Okay, so any method with get prefix in action class is a  getter method and since I have created a list in this method itself, it also becomes action class attribute? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `countries` in

```
countries[0]
```

it calls for `getCountries()` method. Now as you've put `[0]` next to it and `countries` being a list...

it translates to

```
getCountries().get(0)
```

You can verify the same by putting a `sysout` in the `getCountries()` method.

Comment: I think I pretty much got it, by creating a list inside (local) the getCountries, it becomes a part of the action class attribute and hence can be accessed. And any method with get prefix acts as a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

In struts, we use "property" attribute to access the value of a bean, when we use property attribute, its getter method will be called, hence in the above code getCountries() method is getting called.